# TechTalk.SpecFlow Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow

After updating to SpecFlow 2.3.2, I am getting the following error:

**Message: Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=2.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).**

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Really at a loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When do you get this exception?

Comment: I found the solution to my issue. I had to go to my packages directory and remove the 2.2 version of SpecFlow.

Comment: I'm with the same issue.
I followed your suggestion about delete the older version but it didn´t solve.